# Excel Vba Worksheets.range.copy method not working with Dropdownlist

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dropdownlist and in the event of selecting an entry a macro will fire up.
The Dropdown List is in Cell B5 and my code is

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Workbooks("Myfile.xlsm").Activate
Worksheets("Mastermap").Activate

If Target.Address = "$B$5" Then
'Set Events false
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim sfilter As String

'This is the String in the Dropdownlist and resembles the worksheetname
sfilter = Range("B5").Value 

Worksheets(sfilter).Activate
lastrow = Sheets(sfilter).Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
lastcol = Sheets(sfilter).Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Worksheets(sfilter).Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Copy

Worksheets("Mastermap").Activate
Worksheets("Mastermap").Range("D6").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Selection.EntireColumn.AutoFit

Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

After debug I've found out that this throws me the error

```
Worksheets(sfilter).Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(lastrow, lastcol)).Copy
```

So my question is why?
I thought I could use that to copy the range of the cells?
Using the immediate window then everything works fine though...
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Whats the actual error message? Also, please read up on why we shouldn't use things like `Activate` or `Select` in VBA

Comment: I don't actually get an error message.. but it just doesn't work. Like if I run this then nothing will happen

Comment: Bit confused.. you say: `After debug I've found out that this throws me the error` and now you are saying you don't get an error. Both these statements can't be true. Can you clarify which is it?

Comment: Sorry! After the error message, I don't get a new error message. The first error message after using the macro is 'Run-time error 1004' and 'Application-defined or object-defined error'

Comment: Can you step through and find out what the values are for `sfilter, lastrow, lastcol`?

Comment: sfilter, lastrow and lastcol were correct. Maybe the problem is because I have used it in the worksheet instead of a module. So I have changed my code into a subprocedure in a separate module and call it with the worksheet change event...
It is the exact same code btw. It is working for now, but it's not the exact way I wanted to use it. Still thank you.